# Rename automatically console tab name when I put a command into Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to rename automatically console tab name when I put a command ?

When I put elasticSearch into command console, I want [that result](http://www.noelshack.com/2015-30-1437727784-tab.png).

But I have to rename manually.

It's possible with custom command ?

Answer (score 1):

As of IntelliJ IDEA 14.1, there is no possibility to do that automatically.

Comment: Ok, so i'm waiting new possibilies. thk.